# How do I load a resource in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to load something like a properties or XML file from within my JS (web page) (like including a .js file in the .html).

Right now I have some resources included as <script type="resources">blabla</script> and locate these in the DOM, but I'd like to externalize the resources into an extra file. How can I access the contents in my JS?

Searching for "resources" and JS only yields all kinds of C#/ASP questions.

edit: tried escaping angle brackets, so you can actually see my example.

Comment: Where is this resource file you wish to load located?

Comment: The resource can be just anywhere, like I would normally include local JS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the resource is on the same domain you can simply use an ajax call from within your JS file. If it is on another domain you should set up CORS correctly. The file that you fetch will be available for you as a plain txt  (or whatever you want) as long as you set the contentType to the correct value in the response header.

For instance using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/path/to/your/file.xml', function(data) {
        // Here you can do whatever you want with the data 
        $(data).find('option').each(function() {
           alert($(this).text());
        })
    });
});
```

This would alert 4 times with 1, 2, 3 and 4 as the alert text when loading this xml file:

```
<properties>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Ajax", i.e. GET requests using XmlHttpRequest, to load resources after the initial page load.

I'm going to use jQuery (a JavaScript library) to answer just because vanilla JS is a pain to bother with:

```
$.get("resource.xml", function(data) { xml = data; xmlIsReady(data); })
```

Where you'd do further processing on the data in `xmlIsReady`. You may also want to look into the [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) methods. I haven't done any error handling, but you should probably have it.